# When element is 'display:none', how can I upload a image file?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'd like to upload a file by Selenium.
The page url is below.

```
<div class="async-upload__thumb item-image__area">
  <div class="fab-dialog__thumb-drop-zone async-upload__thumb-drop-zone">
    <p class="async-upload__thumb-msg" display="none">SELECT IMAGE</p>
    <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" multiple="" style="display:none">
 </div>
</div>
```

But input element is  `display="none"` so I uploaded a file by this code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("test.jpg");
```

I got error like this:

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds
```

How can I upload an image file?

Comment: Is it always hidden or come the file upload option when you click some option

Comment: Another thing is how do you uploading the file manually ?

Comment: what happens if you delete this `style` attribute manually before this line in webdirver code executes, does it solves the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this will work or not, but you can remove the style attribute.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element);
```

You might need to get the Element again, as its attribute has changed or you might get `StaleElementException`

after the above code following line should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("test.jpg");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried the code.But I got this error.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: args is not defined
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds

Comment: there was a typo error, I have fixed it and now it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now Selenium can upload a image file!!

※Note : first line needs ->  ;

Comment: Be aware that unhidding the `<input>` will defeat the purpose of the test if the goal is to test the feature. A better way is to override the `click` with a script injection to avoid the dialogue. Then click the area which should unhide the `<input>` and call `sendKeys` to set the file.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by this code.
It's remove display:none form input element.

```
    // Remove display : none
    // JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    // js.executeScript("$(\"input[type='file']\").css('display','')");
```

Then appear the select image button and sendKeys().